# Phone Dead after Format all+ download sp flash tool

Tags: rom-flashing, flashtool

Recently i have used SP flash tool for flashing Micromax Canvas a1. I flashed successfully. But i am unable to start the OS. So once again i done "format all+download". But now my phone completely dead . Please help any one how to write NVRAM files (including factory logo and imei no).. But still i am able to flash the mobile using SP flash tool. But mobile not getting ON.. Please help any one

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: badly No :(.. @vzhen.  I kept the mobile aside and purchased alternate one